# Why the function call never gets executed?

Tags: scala

I have a function defined like

```
def counter(x: Int) = {
  var i = x
  () => {
    i = i + 1
    println(i)
  }
}

val count = counter(0)
```

So `count` is a function taking no parameter returning Unit. Then the parenthesis could be omitted when calling `count`. But if I call it by just saying `count`, `i` in fact will not be added and nothing happens. In the meantime, a compiler warning will be given like "A pure expression does nothing you may be omitting the parenthesis".

If I call it with parentheses like `count()`, everything is all right and increased `i` will be printed.

Why saying `count` doesn't work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call function without parentheses. In `scala` you can call `method` without arguments with no parentheses. Method, but not function.

Actually "call function" means "call method `apply` of object of type `FunctionN`" in `scala`.

So `count()` means `count.apply()`. You can call method `apply` with no parentheses like this: `count.apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Your counter(x:Int) method actually returns the function () => { ... } you have defined (which returns Unit and generates the compiler warning).

So by calling count with parentheses, you actually execute the function.

If I desugar type inference, you obtain:

```
def counter(x: Int): () => Unit = {
  var i = x
  () => {
    i = i + 1
    println(i)
  }
}

val count: () => Unit = counter(0)
```

Comment: But it's a function with no argument, so I suppose I could call it with no parentheses just saying `count` rather than `count()`?

Answer (score 0):

A `Function0` does not correspond to a parameterless method exactly.  That is to say:

```
val returnOne = () => 1

// approximates
def returnOne() = 1

// rather than 
def returnOne = 1
```

In fact, once you lift a parameterless method to a `Function0` the parameterless method behavior is lost:

```
// Define a parameterless method
scala> def returnOne = 1
returnOne: Int

// Every time you reference the method it is evaluated
scala> returnOne
res2: Int = 1

// Lift the method to a Function0
scala> returnOne _
res3: () => Int = <function0>

// Now a reference to the lifted method evaluates to the lifted method
scala> res3
res4: () => Int = <function0>

// And you have to invoke it explicitly
scala> res3()
res5: Int = 1
```